# Can I share "C" wire on two thermostats?

Tags: wiring, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I am wiring a second thermostat right next to the original one. The new needs a C wire. Can I share it from the old one?

Old: 8 wires, used to run heat pump (w/ heating and AC) and backup oil. Now only runs AC from heat pump on occasional summer day.

New: Has 2 wires run to it. Controls instant on hot water heater for radiant system.

The new thermostat says, "WILL NOT OPERATE WITHOUT WIRE TO 'C'". Can I take the C wire from the existing thermostat and bridge it to the new thermostat? Can two thermostats share this C wire?

According to [Can I piggyback a thermostat with a C Wire hookup on a furnace?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/9878/can-i-piggyback-a-thermostat-with-a-c-wire-hookup-on-a-furnace?rq=1)  I think the answer is "Yes", but when I try it, the new thermostat does not have power.

Comment: The `R` wire going to the new thermostat, does it come from the same place as the `C` wire on the old thermostat? Or is there an `R` wire from the heat pump to thermostat 1, and an `R` wire from the boiler to thermostat 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only share the `C` wire, if you're also sharing the `R` wire.  If the `R` wires come from different equipment, the `C` wires must also come from the different equipment.

Comment: Is there any reason I shouldn't also share the `R` wires? Based on https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10482/how-can-i-add-a-c-wire-to-my-thermostat I think so, but I wouldn't want one system to start interacting with the other. Just share power.

Comment: You should not share the control wiring between separate systems.

Comment: According to graphics in the link I gave above, the loop only closes when `W` is triggered. It seems like if `C` and `R` were each wired to two systems, the circuits would still be incomplete until `W` triggered, and then only the circuit with the `W` would be active...

Comment: @mankoff The loop from `R` to `C` does not rely on `W` at all. That's why those two are used to supply constant power to the thermostat.